# Is there any prohibition on using tracing chips under the skin?

Tags: technology

With the advance on technology, ethical discussions are being raised regarding implants under one's skin, like a parent, worried about the whereabouts of their kids, or companies thinking about the productivity of their employees or safety of the merchandise (like tracing a truck driver who is part of their logistics team, for instance).

Could the prohibitions regarding the use of eletronics on Shabbat apply here. Or the issue relates to privacy, perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps tattooing

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101122/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-indech-is-there-any-prohibition-on-using-tracin).

Comment: How does this differ from using a watch with a battery on Shabbat?